# Spark 2.0.2 nested K-means in rdds/nested rdds or dataframes or datasets

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to run lots of k-means in parallel. I have a room and lots of data for it and i would like to calculate clusters for each room. So i have

```
roomsSignals[(room:String, signals:List[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]]

roomsSignals.map{l=>
val data=sc.parallelize(l.signals)
 val clusterCenters=2
 val model = KMeans.train(data, clusterCenters, 5)
    model.clusterCenters.map { r =>r.toJson.toString}.mkString(",")

}.collect.foreach(println)
```

Which gives me the error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 33 in stage 18.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 33.3 in stage 18.0 (TID 1284, 192.168.181.122):     java.lang.NullPointerException
at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:77)
at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:76)
at scala.collection.Iter    ator$$anon$11.next(Iter    ator.scala:409)
at scala.collection.Iter    ator$class.foreach(Iter    ator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIter    ator.foreach(Iter    ator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
at scala.collection.AbstractIter    ator.to(Iter    ator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
at scala.collection.AbstractIter    ator.toBuffer(Iter    ator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
at scala.collection.AbstractIter    ator.toArray(Iter    ator.scala:1336)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:912)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:912)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1916)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1916)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1454)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1442)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
```

Comment: Please paste the full stacktrace and include the driver stacktrace as well !

Comment: i posted some of it can not put it all because of the limitation

Comment: Then just see for yourself where the error is ! It will provide you the exact line in the driver's stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible. Any type of nesting of this kind is not supported by Spark at all.

Either train independent distributed models iterating over `roomsSignals.collect` or use local library of choice to build models in distributed structure.

Comment: I know it was not possible in spark 1.3 i would get exception of spark context not serialisable, I thought spark progressed sense then.

Comment: It didn't and it won't. You couldn't implement anything like this without significantly limiting Spark capabilities.